# Spring Security Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, netbeans-8

Im creating a spring website with security in netbeans with out maven.  I keep reading about adding dependencies in pom.xml, but i didnt create my project with maven so theres no pom.xml file.  I keep getting this error while trying to set up the security.  The error is happening in spring-security.xml file.  If I dont add it in web.xml, the project works fine but it doesn't work when i include it in web.xml.  I copied the spring security Jar/folders from the maven respiratory.

This is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">

    <!-- Configs -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
            /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!--- Listeners -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Spring MVC DispatcherServlet -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            3
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
         <init-param>
            <param-name>contextAttribute</param-name>
            <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext.ROOT</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>   
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

This is my spring-security.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
              xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

    <http auto-config="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin*" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
        <form-login login-page='login.jsp'/>
        <logout logout-success-url="/index" />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="lun" password="lun" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

Comment: "from the maven *respiratory*" - the word you are looking for is: repository. :)

Comment: Did you add the transistive dependencies as well? What stacktrace did you get? Besides that: I would strongly encourage you to use a dependency management tool like maven, gradle (which uses maven underneath), ivy etc. It will save you a lot of time and keep you from fiddling with missing jars, or wrong versions of jars.